# Does Redshift unload command with parallel on guarantees sorted data with the use of order by clause?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I currently don't have enough data to test the scenario but I need to know if Redshift `unload` command with `parallel on` unloads sorted data to multi part files on s3, if I use order by clause with `unload` query? I know I can unload sorted data to s3 serially with 6.2 GB on each part if I use `parallel off`.

Redshift documentation states about [unload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html):

> A SELECT query. The results of the query are unloaded. In most cases, it is worthwhile to unload data in sorted order by specifying an ORDER BY clause in the query; this approach saves the time required to sort the data when it is reloaded.

Any related link with this topic would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching a lot I found my answer.

According to [Redshift docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html):

> By default, UNLOAD writes data in parallel to multiple files, according to the number of slices in the cluster. To write data to a single file, specify PARALLEL OFF. UNLOAD writes the data serially, sorted absolutely according to the ORDER BY clause, if one is used. The maximum size for a data file is 6.2 GB. If the data size is greater than the maximum, UNLOAD creates additional files, up to 6.2 GB each.

So it is required to use `parallel off` if one needs sorted data.